# Repeated RemoveContent using msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a directory structure that looks like the below. I don't know ahead of time how many PARENT folders there will be, but I do know that each one will contain exactly one folder named DATA. The name of the DATA folder does not change, but the PARENT folders could be called anything.

I would like to delete all the *contents* of the DATA folders, but leave the DATA folders themselves in places, using msbuild.

I know that you can use the msbuild Community Tasks/extension RemoveContent task to remove all subdirectories and files from a folder without deleting the folder itself, but I can't figure out how to select all the DATA folders and call RemoveContent on each.

```
TOP
  - PARENT1
    - FOLDER1
    - FOLDER2
    - DATA
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
  - PARENT2
    - FOLDER1 
    - DATA
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
  - PARENT3
    - FOLDERABC
    - DATA
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
      - SUBFOLDER
          - SUBSUBFOLDER1
            - <files>
          - SUBSUBFOLDER2
            - <files>
  - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the directories using [a property function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) using System.IO.GetDirectories since that allows listing direstories using wildcards easily, then batch over the list using the RemoveContent task. Should be something like this:

```
<Target Name="EraseEverythingUnderAllDataDirs">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Dirs Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`path\toTOP`,`DATA`,System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Folder TaskAction="RemoveContent" 
                                           Path="%(Dirs.Identity)"/>
</Target>
```

I'd suggest first checking if this is what you want, using the Message task instead of RemoveContent. No kidding, I once started RemoveContent on c:\ by accident and was *not* amused with the result.